# Fill group of rows with incremental shades of color

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to fill each row with an incremental shade of a base color (or some range). So far, I could do it using Conditional Formatting with a "rule" based on the ascending numerical values.
[image]

However, I wish to achieve the same effect with the group of rows that have no content. Is there an automatic way to do it?

EDIT:

There are 6 rows in the column. Currently they are color-filled from white to orange with incremented shades. Such color fill is done automatically using Conditional formatting rule that maps the shades of the color to the values (1-6) in the rows. I wish to fill an arbitrary number of rows with such incremental colors without dependency on the actual content of the cells. Thus, if I select 10 rows, I want to see each row of slightly darker shade of the specified color, BUT even if the cells are empty.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? In the row with `1`, `2`, etc. do you also want the cells in columns left and right of those numbers to have that same shading?

Comment: @BruceWayne Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

*Colour Scale can be applied on Data Range, either you pick the Predefined Scales or Customize the Scale, and if you want to Customize the Scale, Cell Values are required to Justify the rule.*

It's very simple to Customize the Data Range for it. Follow these steps.

1. Select the Data Range **(I'm assuming it A2:B20)**.
2. Click Conditional Formatting.
3. Hit New Rule, use Formula.
4. Assign the Formula =$B2>=1
5. Apply appropriate colour.
6. Repeat steps 1 to 3 or Click Manage Rule.
7. Write this Formula =$B2>=3 and apply appropriate Colour.

**NB:** Continue with the steps and design as per Values in Column B. Like Next =$B2>=5 and so on.

*OR you may test Range of Values like =and($B2>=5,$B2<=9).*

Hope this help you.

Comment: This approach seems to still depend on the values in the cells (though I could not reproduce it). The cells will contain text, so I can not have color depend on the text value. I though there would be a way to tie the color dependency to the row number.